# Azure Cloud PowerShell return output got replaced with dot dot dot

Tags: azure, powershell, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Azure Cloud PowerShell to get access token by using

```
$postParams = @{"client_id"="xxx3f7c-2a52-4be8-a7cf-1b499ee58d4d";
"scope"="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
"client_secret"="xxxL66S-h4pMnIPZrR7-..9L7NnyU9B4";
"grant_type"="client_credentials"
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxaab-164a-4603-b614-9405173c5351/oauth2/v2.0/token -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

However, the returned token got truncated and replaced with ... without ending quote for content attribute.

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":3599,"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKxxxiLCJub25jZSI6IlV3YTF4NWJYZnE2V3hOS211TFVqNEJYaTNIZGVKNExLeEZSSFMxVGs4eWsiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5Pb…
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
                    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                    P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN…
Headers           : {[Cache-Control, System.String[]], [Pragma, System.String[]], [Strict-Transport-Security, System.String[]], [X-Content-Type-Options, System.String[]], [P3P, System.String[]], [x-ms-request-id, System.String[]],
                    [x-ms-ests-server, System.String[]], [Set-Cookie, System.String[]], [Date, System.String[]], [Content-Type, System.String[]], [Expires, System.String[]], [Content-Length, System.String[]]}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
RawContentLength  : 1507
RelationLink      : {}
```

The content attribute ends with m5Pb… which is not complete. How can I get the full token content from Azure Cloud PowerShell?

Comment: If you save the request to a variable and then call the the `Content` property is it still truncated? `$req = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http.....` and `$req.Content`

Comment: The truncation is only in the output, simply because it doesn't fit the display. Inside `$req.Content | ConvertFrom-Json` it is complete.

Comment: Hi, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer to end the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Santiago Squarzon said is right, you need to save the request to a variable, and then call the `Content` property, it will return the complete access token.

```
$postParams = @{"client_id"="ab717ac0-4abe-449d-aeb3-685c86c22xxx";
"scope"="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
"client_secret"="U5BPXYvLy2oO.5JE.Y.Ty3d~7b281W5xxx";
"grant_type"="client_credentials"
}

$req=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/oauth2/v2.0/token -Method POST -Body $postParams

$req.Content
```

[image]